# Navigation Component with NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I am trying to implement NavigationDrawer with Navigation Component in my project.
I have a MainActivity as an entry point and multiple fragments destinations. I have linked my Drawer menu Items to Destinations in my nav_graph.xml everything works just fine.

I have a "Logout" menu item option in my NavigationDrawer and on clicking on it I am launching LoginActivity. My questions are

1. I added LoginActivity to my nav_graph and linked it to logout menu item in drawer, Is this the correct way?
2. Once LoginActivity is launched, when user press system back button, I want the app to go to launcher screen instead of previous destination in the stack. Is this possible to achieve with Navgation Component?

Here is my nav_graph.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/dashboardFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/dashboardFragment"
        android:name="com.example.fragment.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="DashboardFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
        android:name="com.example.fragment.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="ProfileFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
        android:name="com.example.fragment.SettingsFragment"
        android:label="SettingsFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sale_edit" />
    <activity
        android:id="@+id/loginActivity"
        android:name="com.example.activity.LogoutActivity"
        android:label="LogoutActivity"></activity>
</navigation>
```

Here is my drawer_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigationView">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/dashboardFragment"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Dashboard" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Profile" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Sale Edits" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/loginActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Logout" />
    </group>

</menu>



<fragment
        android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"/>
```

Comment: Why not to use fragment instead of activity for login?

Comment: Sorry for late relply.
By making login as fragment, it makes the toolbar appear for login screen as well, I do not want to have the toolbar in Login screen also that will be overhead of creating toolbar for each fragment when it is same for all of them.
 I have a different flow altogether for login screen, for example Login->signup or Login-> forgot password etc. I do not want to mix up them

Comment: You can use login as fragment and handle the toolbar logic from main activity inside NavHostFragment.findNavController( nav_host_fragment ).addOnNavigatedListener(), it is better solution than login activity.

Comment: You mean, in this case hide the toolbar programatically when user click logout option? and show it back again after login?

Comment: Yes, handle the toolbar logic based on current destination, i added some code here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51491743/1268507

Answer (score 2):

I think the better solution will be using login as fragment and not activity, and toolbar handling should be done from your activity.
Your activity should look something like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(this, findNavController(nav_host_fragment),drawer_layout)
    setupWithNavController(nav_view, findNavController(nav_host_fragment))

    NavHostFragment.findNavController( nav_host_fragment ).addOnNavigatedListener { controller, destination ->
        when(destination.id) {
            R.id.loginFragment -> {
                drawer_layout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)
                toolbar.visibility= View.GONE
            }
            R.id.dashboardFragment -> {
                drawer_layout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED)
                toolbar.visibility= View.VISIBLE
            }
            else -> {
                drawer_layout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)
                toolbar.visibility= View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    when(item?.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> {
            if(NavHostFragment.findNavController( nav_host_fragment ).currentDestination.id==R.id.dashboardFragment) {
                drawer_layout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp()= findNavController(nav_host_fragment).navigateUp()
```

Comment: I know this could be the way, But I end up writing too much of code(not needed) here and also merging different Nav Graphs into one is hard to maintain in future. For now I just separated the Navgraphs for login and main screens and I am using Intent to go back to launcher when user click on back button on login screen.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

> I added LoginActivity to my nav_graph and linked it to logout menu item in drawer, Is this the correct way?

Yes, That is how you are supposed to lunch a new activity but what you want is a little different than a regular activity.

To achieve what you want, you have to start your application with the loginActivity (make it be your launcher activity) and this activity would check the user's session (have a splash screen or loading screen) and if a session exists, it would lunch your main activity and if not user has to login and then you lunch the main activity.

To do this with the navigation component you need to create a new navigation graph for the login activity and have your main activity link there.

With this setup, you should lunch the main activity in a new task and then finish your login activity, that way going back on main activity will close the application as well as going back from the login activity.

Let me know if this answer is not clear and I can explain more.

Comment: I think adding Splash screen is not the modern way of doing Android Apps. 
Also, It is not recommended to make Login screen as start destination as per Navigation Principles that I have read here
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-principles

Comment: @android_user It depends very much on your application, splash screen is to provide a transition to the app while you are checking user's session, but if that is instant and doesn't take any time then you don't need a splash. The NavComponent is still being developed and as its current state, navigating between activities and nestedGraphs are not up to industry practices (at least I couldn't accomplish all of my needs) so you can either implement a custom navigator to fit your need or take my suggestion until there is a better way of doing it. please let me know if you find any other solution

Comment: My App design does not require a Splash Screen. I do not have much data to load on my app startup and my NavCompoment without Splash screen works pretty well. Hence, for now I haven't changed anything except when user clicks system back on login screen I am just using Intent to go back to launcher screen, This way I am able to achieve what I can. There could be a better solution for this in future.

Answer (score 0):

I've also been trying to find a solution to this and it was pretty simple in the end.

!!! Remove the activity navigation item from `nav_graph.xml` and all code instances where that is handled or wired. (For example I use AppBarConfiguration, had to remove the id from there)

Just use the click listener for the menu item you want to handle from your navigation drawer.

```
navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
val logoutItem = navView.menu.findItem(R.id.loginActivity)
logoutItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
    val loginIntent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(loginIntent)
    finish()
    return@setOnMenuItemClickListener true
}
```